# Do I use cookies?

Tags: cookies

I have made website in wordpress, and now client wants to know do this website use cookies?

I dont know too much about it becouse i never use it, but i need to be sure. If I make websites i use session, and I quess the same is in wordpress, but as I said, dont know too much about it and client need this information.

I also use PIWIK stats.

Is there a way to check it? I can give you list of plugins I used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, any WordPress site does uses cookies. By default, WordPress uses cookies to verify who the user is, i.e. if the user is logged-in (registered user) or is a commenter on the site. ([More Info.](http://codex.wordpress.org/WordPress_Cookies))

Plugins and theme's may set cookies. For example, [Cookies for Comments](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/cookies-for-comments/) plugin uses cookies to prevent comment spam. Cookies have their own purpose.

Check your browser preferences (or in the dialog box when deleting history), you should see an option similar to "Manage Cookies", which shows a list of cookies sent by your website.

**BTW**, WordPress does not use sessions.

Comment: Thank you for help. This is solicitor' website, and cookies policy has been changed. Now when users go to a website which use cookies, should be able to accept or not cookies, or unleast be inform that this website use cookies. Is htere a way to accept or deny cookies access? I'm thinking about popoup window with information aout this fact or questions and 2 buttons: *Allow* and *Deny*.

Comment: @miszczu Sorry, I am not aware of those possibilities. And I do see that you've asked a question on that.

Comment: Yea, thanks anyway. I just need to explain it to client, they are lawyers, so i need to do it asap and good :)